# Move the file to other location

Tags: java, exception, copy, move

I need to move the file to other location giving it differnt name.
What I tried to do is :

```
Files.move(oldName, newName, options);
```

I get an exception:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /media/sf_VboxShared/Data/csv/res20150201/xx/part-r-00000-f8ed41a5-e0e1-4534-a1d9-e4d6082691db.gz.parquet -> /media/sf_VboxShared/Data/csv/res20150201/res/xx.parquet
```

The `oldName` file exists. `newName` dosn`t exist. (Only this `/media/sf_VboxShared/Data/csv/res20150201` part of the path exist)

Answer (score 1):

You can create missing parent directories by calling:

```
Files.createDirectories( Paths.get( <your file path> ).getParent() );
```

Comment: No need to wrap it with a legacy File object. Actually this wouldn't even compile as newName is a Path object.

Comment: @Puce Right, it takes a Path and not a File instance on parameter. I have just edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

You say that `/media/sf_VboxShared/Data/csv/res20150201`, but the parent directory of the directory that you want to move the file to, `/media/sf_VboxShared/Data/csv/res20150201/xx`, doesn't exist.

So you have to create it first before moving:

```
Path newName = ...;
Files.createDirectories(newName.getParent());
```